# Expected 'styleUrls' to be an array of strings aith webpack 4 and angular 5

Tags: css, angular, webpack

I'm updating a project to new webpack and angular versions.
My `webpack.config` is as follows:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        presets: ['es2015']
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.(jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)$/,
      loader: "url-loader?name=[name].[hash:20].[ext]&limit=10000"
    },
    {
      test: /\.ts$/,
      loaders: ['ts-loader', 'angular2-template-loader?keepUrl=true'],
      exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ['style-loader', {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: false,
          importLoaders: 1
        }
      }, 'postcss-loader']
    },
    {
      test: /\.html$/,
      use: 'raw-loader'
    },
    {
      test: /\.(svg)$/,
      loader: 'html-loader'
    },
  ]
}
```

and `postcss.config`:

```
module.exports = {
  parser: 'postcss-scss',
  plugins: {
    'postcss-import': {},
    'postcss-cssnext': {},
    'cssnano': {}
  }
```

Now I'm getting an error in the title of the question.
I know it was asked several times, but none of the answers helped me. What's wrong with my configs?
    }

All my components have something like `styleUrls: ['./component.style.css']`. So I guess the problem is that those files can not be read. But I don't have an idea why

Comment: The error seems quite self-explanatory. You probably have a component where `styleUrls` is not an array of strings

Comment: @bugs no, that's not the case. I've checked - all the components have something like `styleUrls: ['./cmpName.style.css']`